# SQL Server: calculate variable dates in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, getdate

is there a way in SQL that I can calculate the following in a stored procedure using GETDATE() or something similar ?

- First Monday in March of current year
- Last Monday in May of current year
- Third Friday in October of current year

Also, I am looking for a way to add specific dates to the above list, e.g. April 1 of the current year.

I hope someone here can help me with this. Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Have a look at [first Monday of Week/Month – TSQL
How to get first Monday of Week/Month – TSQL](http://sqlandme.com/2011/05/18/how-to-get-first-monday-week-month-tsql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to calculate it, here are 3 examples

```
declare @month int = 6

select 
    -- first Monday in @month of current year
    dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month-1, 
      dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 6)))/7*7, 0),
    -- last Monday in @month of current year
    dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month, 
      dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 6)))/7*7, -7),
    -- third Friday in @month of current year
    dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(m, @month-1, 
      dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 3)))/7*7, 18)
```

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot !n Can you explain what the declare line does ?

Comment: the declare is preparing a variable (month) and setting it to the numeric value of the month(june). That way you can find the day you need for that same month. There is an easier way to find end of month and start of month in sqlserver 2012. Read about it here [EOMONTH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is where using a Calendar table can come in very handy.

http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

You can then simply join to the table to determine what you are looking for.

For example, finding the first monday in march of the current year:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dt 
  FROM dbo.CALENDAR 
 WHERE Y = @currentyear and M = 3 and DW = 2 
 ORDER by dt
```

For more complex things, you can use ROW_NUMBER() and ordering to figure out the "third friday", etc...

Comment: Thanks, I understand using this for fixed dates but how would it help with the above variable dates ?

Comment: Note that the article is pretty old - if you're on a later version of sql server, use the DATE instead of DATETIME data type for your DT column, so you don't have to mess with times.